# Modular pattern in Google Apps Scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a GAS library using a modular pattern approach.
As the main object is growing in size, I would like to split the code in separate files, to maintain a simple overview of the project.
In the web editor, I can create additional scripts within my main script via File > New > Script file.
Can I cross reference methods and variables from file to file? Do they share namespace?
Is there a better approach to address this problem?

Comment: They do share a namespace indeed (global), but keep in mind that everything that's is in the global namespace would be aviable to consumers of your library. I'm intesrested in knowing if there are more experienced users willing to share their Library Architecture. Also make sure you [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Comment: @mTorres I am also interested to discuss Library Architecture. You can find me on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JasperDuizendstraPersonal)

Comment: And as you probably know you can add an underscore to the end of any functions you don't want to be visible outside the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No solid solution for this I think. You could put the public methods of the object in another .gs file and add them to the prototype. But this has other drawbacks. But it is an option.

My rule is one object per .gs file. If it grows large, there are probably other issues and I move certain task of the object to other objects.

Objects are in the global namespace so they can be placed in separate .gs files.